# The grammatical usage of verb to be in 'Whether we be old'

Tags: infinitives, present-simple

I was reading Harry Potter when I stumbled across this phrase in a song.

> *Whether we be old and bald*

And this is the part of the song containing the phrase for a better understanding of the context.

> *Teach us something please*

> *Whether we be old and bald*

> *Or young with scabby knees*

I don't understand why verb to be is put in an infinitive form. It sounds good to my ear but shouldn't it be phrased like this: *Whether we **are** old and bald*

What's the grammar behind phrasing it the way it is, does it give any difference in meaning than the usual present form?

Comment: The difference is that subjunctive "be" is relatively formal. Apparently, it's fairly common, especially in the ungoverned construction, as seen in your example.

Comment: Is the word "wether" spelled correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *Whether we be old and bald*
>
> [2] *Whether we are old and bald*

These both have the meaning, though the subjunctive form in [1] is considered overly-formal, perhaps even old-fashioned to some speakers, and hence is less likely than [2].

Syntactically, they are both adjuncts functioning as part of an 'exhaustive conditional' construction.